# I am not understanding how the code is working as a recursion function

Tags: python

```
def tri_recursion(k):
if(k > 0):
    result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
    print(result)
else:
    result = 0
return result

print("Recursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

*As in the first iteration of the code `result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)`* it is returning 6. but as per my understanding it should be `result = 6+(6-1) = 11`. but in the output it is showing

```
Recursion Example Results
```

1

3

6

10

15

21

Comment: This looks familiar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73769746/i-am-bit-confuse-how-the-recursion-function-call-the-output-that-is-mentioned

Comment: But Kindly help please as I am not getting how it is working. As per your referal link , the reply is 6+5+4+3+2+1=21 and vice versa. But My question is how it will call 6 instead of 6+(6-1) according to result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1) in result

Comment: `tri_recursion` receives `k - 1` as argument, the `k` before it is irrelevant to this value.

Comment: I am not getting how output is working.

Answer (score 0):

You could just "unroll" the recursion in a small case (e.g., `k=2`) to see what happens:

```py
k = 2
#tri_recursion(k=2) BEGIN
if(k > 0):

    #tri_recursion(k=1) BEGIN
    k=1         # k = k-1
    if(k > 0):

        #tri_recursion(k=0) BEGIN
        k=0         # k = k-1
        if(k > 0):
            # [result = k + ...] -> k==0, thus not evaluated
            pass
        else:
            result = 0       # sets result=0
        #tri_recursion(k=0) END
        k = 1   # retrieve value of k from outer function

        result = k + result  # result=1+0
        print(result)        # print(1)
    else:
       # result = 0 -> k==1, thus not evaluated
       pass
    #tri_recursion(k=1) END
    k = 2   # retrieve value of k from outer function

    result = k + result      # result=2+1
    print(result)            # print(3)
else:
    # result = 0 -> k==2, thus not evaluated
    pass

#tri_recursion(k=2) END
```

This piece of code reproduces what happens inside your function call without any recursion or loops. Upon a call to `tri_recursion(k=2)`, the interpreter goes inside the `if (k>0)` clause, then evaluates `result = k + tri_recursion(k-1)`, but for its evaluation it must call itself with `k-1` in `tri_recursion(k-1)` (hence the recursion). Repeat that `k` times and you get the full function evaluation.

Comment: Thank you for such a great support. Now understand..